# Jackson UpperCamelCase - not capitalizing single word properties

Tags: java, json, serialization, jackson, fasterxml

I'm converting serialization from snake to upper camel case.

```
mapper.setPropertyNamingStrategy(PropertyNamingStrategy.UPPER_CAMEL_CASE);
```

While updating the tests I've noticed that single word properties are not capitalized:

```
{"priority":3, "CorrelationId":"cce2dfa6-f82a-11e6-bc64-92361f002671"}
```

Is this an expected behavior? What is the solution for single word properties?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The actual problem was in JsonProperty annotation in snake case that given weird results:

```
@JsonProperty("priority"), @JsonProperty("correlation_id")
```

After fixing them to upper camel case the problem was gone.

Answer (score 1):

A `PropertyNamingStrategy` is only applied to POJOs, according to its [javadoc](https://static.javadoc.io/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-databind/2.8.7/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/PropertyNamingStrategy.html) :

> defines how names of JSON properties ("external names") are derived
>   from names of POJO methods and fields ("internal names")

My guess is that you're passing a collection type to the mapper, which will not be affected by the strategy.

Comment: "priority" is s field and I have propery getters and setters visiblitiy disabled in mapper.

Comment: @Cortlendt: Ok. In that case, I can't replicate the problem. In my sandbox, the naming strategy is applied to the output without a problem.

Comment: a conflict with other mapper settings?

Comment: Possibly. Perhaps try it out in a unit-test, with a "vanilla" `ObjectMapper` and apply your configurations one by one to see when the problem emerges.